# В соответствии с каким правилом ставится тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, стилистическая-ошибка

Это задание, которое у меня **не получилось сделать.**

Вар.1. Задание 21. В соответствии с каким правилом ставится тире?

Найдите предложения, в которых тире ставится в соответствии **с одним и тем же правилом пунктуации. Запишите номера этих предложений.**

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3319529-var1-zadanie-21-v-sootvetstvii-s-kakim-pravilom-stavitsja-tire-sm.html

**Это текст.**

(1) После того как с изобретением винта и реактивного двигателя мир становился для новых поколений все меньше и меньше, родилось представление, что людям прошлого он должен был казаться соответственно больше и до Колумба вообще был бесконечным, а океаны — неодолимыми.

(2) В учебных пособиях, говорящих о судостроении, прочно утвердилось положение, что первоначально человек одолевал небольшие водные пространства верхом на бревне.

(3) Затем, чтобы не мочить ноги, он додумался выдалбливать бревно топором и выжигать огнем, а по мере того как отваживался на поединок со все более высокими волнами — наращивал долбленку досками по бокам.

(4) Несомненно, первая забота человека при создании судов – обеспечить плавучесть.

(5) В разных концах света цель эта достигалась двумя совершенно разными способами.

(6) Один — сборка пропускающей воду конструкции из плавучих элементов, вместе обеспечивающих достаточную плавучесть, чтобы нести команду и груз.

(7) Второй — изготовление водонепроницаемого корпуса, плавучесть которого обеспечивается не родом материала, а за счет вытеснения воды воздухом.

**Это мое решение**

Предложения 1 и 3 — неполные, но у них очень **сомнительная стилистика.** Интересно, кто это сочинил такое?  **Есть ли в них грамматические или стилистические ошибки?**

К тому же в предложении 3 тире обозначает пропуск местоимения *он* и заменяет запятую на стыке двух предложений.  Получается, что предложения  не очень похожи.

В предложении 4 тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, но оно одно такое.

В предложениях 6 и 7 **две причины** для постановки тире: пропуск слова ***способ*** и тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, а правило должно быть одно (судя по вопросу).

**Ну и что мне выбрать? Как, однако, трудно учиться в школе!**

Comment: Чем вас не устроила стилистика в 1 и 3? Как по мне, нормально там всё со стилистикой.

Answer (score 1):

**Этот ответ пока только по стилистике.**

Чем меня не устроила стилистика в 1 и 3?  Как по мне, так это **плохая стилистика**, особенно в предложении 1

**Вариант редактирования**

1) *После того как с изобретением винта и реактивного двигателя мир становился для новых поколений все меньше и меньше, родилось представление **о том,** что людям прошлого он должен был  **бы** казаться соответственно больше, **а  до Колумба  он вообще представлялся бесконечным,  а океаны — непреодолимыми.***

Изъяснительная часть (по семантике и грамматике) разделена на два блока, в то время как в исходном тексте всё перемешано.

2) *Затем, чтобы не мочить ноги, он додумался выдалбливать бревно топором и выжигать огнем,  а по мере того как отваживался на поединок со все более высокими волнами — **стал наращивать** долбленку досками по бокам.*

**Было**: по мере того как отваживался, он наращивал.

**Стало:** по мере того как отваживался, он стал наращивать.

Начало процесса в исходном тексте не обозначено: когда **однажды** отважился, тогда и **стал наращивать**.

Может быть и мелочь, но стилистическая неточность в обозначении времени ощущается (как по мне).

Comment: Sharon, стилистика действительно страдает. Текст невнятный.

Answer (score 1):

В предложениях 1,6,7 тире стоит на месте нулевой связки в составном именном сказуемом:1)... *а океаны —(были) неодолимыми.*

6) *Один — (есть) сборка пропускающей воду конструкции из плавучих элементов.*..

7) *Второй — (есть)изготовление водонепроницаемого корпуса..*.

К этому КИМу есть ответы:  https://nsportal.ru/shkola/russkiy-yazyk/library/2018/10/10/variant-ege-russkiy-yazyk-soglasno-demoversii-2019-goda-s

Comment: Людмила, большое спасибо за ответ. Свой комментарий  я оформила отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 1):

**Отзыв на задание**

Я бы назвала это задание **низкокачественным**. Текст содержит стилистические ошибки,  вопрос составлен **некорректно,** ответы (1, 6, 7) мне представляются **неверными.**

**Пояснение**

В задании присутствуют **две темы**:  (1) постановка тире между подлежащим и  именной частью сказуемого; (2) постановка тире в неполных предложениях.  Можно предположить, что эти темы в задании **не должны пересекаться**, так как они регулируются **различными правилами**.

Тире между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого ставится, если пропущена связка ***есть*** в форме настоящего времени. Связка в форме  прошедшего времени не пропускается, например: ***Мой друг – художник.  Мой друг был художником.***

В неполном же предложении может быть **пропущено любое  слово** или несколько слов, в том числе связка ***был***, а на месте пропуска **при наличии паузы** ставится тире.

**А что мы имеем в задании?**

Тема тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в чистом виде присутствует только в предложении 4.

В предложения 6 и 7 обозначены **обе темы:**

(6) **Один  (способ/из способов)** — сборка пропускающей воду конструкции из плавучих элементов, вместе обеспечивающих достаточную плавучесть, чтобы нести команду и груз.

(7) **Второй (способ)**— изготовление водонепроницаемого корпуса, плавучесть которого обеспечивается не родом материала, а за счет вытеснения воды воздухом.

Эти предложения неполные, пропущенное слово ***способ*** восстанавливается по контексту. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым здесь ставится в любом случае (в полном и неполном варианте). **Поэтому неясно, к какой же теме отнести эти предложения.**

Предложении 1 неполное, пропущена связка ***были.*** Тире ставится **по правилам** неполных предложений, так как в подобных случаях его постановка зависит от структуры конкретного предложения (в некоторых случаях в неполных предложениях тире не ставится).

Получается, что предложение 1 относится к теме неполных предложений, а предложения 6, 7 совмещают две темы.  **Что же  между ними общего?**

И вот такую «мешанину» предлагают ученикам в качестве задания. Остается только задать вопрос:  **кто же контролирует качество подобных «упражнений».**

А ответ, вероятно, подразумевается самый простой: **сами себя и контролируем.**